# Jade class name add without class attribute in loop

Tags: javascript, json, pug

I know this silly question but i am new in this.
How can add the class name without class attribute in each.
I know to add classname with hotcoded. like

```
classname="link" in span tag.
```

we can do like this

```
span.link
```

But in each function how can add the css name in json data.

Sample Json data:

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "icon": "icon1"
    },
    {
      "icon": "icon2"
    },
    {
      "icon": "icon3"
    }
  ]
}
```

each data in data

```
span(class=data.icon)
```

Its working but I need to add classname(from json) without class attribute.

Comment: Why? Any reasons?

Comment: No any particular reason. Just thought in my mind

Comment: You can't add a class without the class attribute...